# Unable to install any package due to unmet dependencies of python-minimal

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, ubuntu-14.04

Whenever I try to install any software on my ubuntu syatem, I am prompted with 'Unmet dependencies' error and is being suggested to do apt install -f.

I tried below command and n number of other ways to solve this, but can't find solution to install any software. Ubuntu version is 14.04

```
 sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libcwidget3 libept1.4.12
  libpython-stdlib python
Suggested packages:
  aptitude-doc-en aptitude-doc tasksel debtags libcwidget-dev python-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aptitude:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libcwidget3 libept1.4.12
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython-stdlib python
2 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,678 kB/2,724 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,544 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libcwidget3 amd64 0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1 [307 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main aptitude amd64 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4 [1,371 kB]
Fetched 1,678 kB in 4s (414 kB/s)     
(Reading database ... 233444 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing aptitude (0.6.6-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude-common.
(Reading database ... 233333 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude-common (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-iostreams1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-iostreams1.54.0:amd64 (1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcwidget3.
Preparing to unpack .../libcwidget3_0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcwidget3 (0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libept1.4.12:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libept1.4.12_1.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libept1.4.12:amd64 (1.0.12) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude.
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude_0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude (0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.14-1~14.04.york0) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py", line 16, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Always I am getting python-minimal error. How to solve this?